# Trying to send eth to smart contract, but get Error: Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available

Tags: next.js, ethereum, smartcontracts

I am able to read values from the contract but am unable to execute the payable functions.

I am thinking it could be something with infura not allowing the sendTransaction method, but i have read that I should be able to use Infura for sending transactions to a smart contract. Here is my function that should send one eth to the function in the smart contract.

```
    function paySubscription(uint256 _period) external payable virtual {
    if(msg.value != ethFee * _period) revert FailedEthTransfer();
    if(paymentExpire[msg.sender] == 0) {
    paymentExpire[msg.sender] = (block.timestamp) + (_period * 30 days);
    } else {
    paymentExpire[msg.sender] += _period * 30 days;
    }

    }
```

```
    const init1 = async () => {
    const web3 = new Web3(infuraUrl);
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    MyContract.abi,
    process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS
    );

    const tx = myContract.methods.paySubscription(1).send({ from: address });
    const gas = await tx.estimateGas({ from: address });
    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
    const data = tx.encodeABI();
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address);

    const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
    {
    to: process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    data,
    value: 1 * 10 ** 9,
    gas,
    gasPrice,
    nonce,
    chainId: networkId,


    },
    privateKey
    );

    console.log(0.000000001 * gas * 1 * 10 ** 9);

    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
    console.log(Transaction hash: ${receipt.transactionHash});
    console.log(New data value: ${await myContract.methods.data().call()});
    };
```